# Submit a Form with Validations using AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a PHP page with Session set on that page . I want to add a form with validations which contains dropdown list(the list displays all projects assigned to employee depending on the empid retrieved from session variable).This form will be processed and the Project selected will be traced so that the employee starts his work on that project.

I want a functionality which will show that the Project has been tracked and rest of the contents should not be refreshed.Only the form should be processed and return the result (as everything has session working and the page is to be accessed only once)

Comment: so, What is your question?

Comment: Try submitting some of your code or your attempts so far, this question is a bit vague!

Comment: I want the code for AJAx ... how this functionality is implemented using AJAX

Comment: if you want ajax code then add your html and php code and add your attemted ajax code.

Comment: When do you need the code?

Comment: Yeah that's nice that you want the code. But unfortunately stackoverflow is no marketplace for free coding jobs :/

Comment: @user3134101: just search google by  php+ajax+form validation you example you will have many many answer and studdy sometimes with it.

Comment: jQuery Form Plugin http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These links may help.

Submit a form with Ajax and jQuery:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

Validate a form:

http://jqueryvalidation.org

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery Form Plugin

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm

I think this will solve your purpose